# Loading binary data through StringIO into a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am doing urlread and I get the following data:

```
text
b'Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume\n2011-10-04,4.936250,5.262500,4.912500,5.262500,5.262500,162400\n2011-10-05,5.441250,5.705000,5.431250,5.673750,5.673750,71200 ....

type(text)
<class 'bytes'>
```

I want to store it in dataframe such that independent columns are created from the header names as:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2011-10-04,4.936250,5.262500,4.912500,5.262500,5.262500,162400
2011-10-05,5.441250,5.705000,5.431250,5.673750,5.673750,71200
```

I want to parse the Date column as datetime also.

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
data = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(text.decode("utf-8")))
```

But above gives dataframe of shape `2x1` instead of shape `2x7` where each row appears as a string

Comment: `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text.decode("utf-8")))`?

Comment: Thanks .. didn't know it was that straightforward

Comment: No problem. Published an answer for posterity. Feel free to mark accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) reads fixed with formatted lines. This is makes sense if your columns are regular in size.

In your case, however, your data appears to be a csv snip. You should use [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) instead:

```
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text.decode("utf-8")))
```